# Unreachable Code warning in http4s route pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, http4s

I have this simple Route defined with *http4s*:

```
def routes: HttpRoutes[UserTask] =
    HttpRoutes.of[UserTask] {
      case GET -> Root / IntVar(id) =>
        ... // returns a specific user
      case GET -> Root => // this line gives the warning
        Persistence.>.all().foldM( ... // returns all users
      case request@POST -> Root =>
      ....

    }
```

The Route works as expected.

Is there a way to avoid this warning?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
[info] Compiling 21 Scala sources to /Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/zio-examples/out/entity/compile/dest/classes ...
[warn] /Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/zio-examples/entity/src/pme123/zio/examples/api/Api.scala:24:34: unreachable code
[warn]         Persistence.>.all().foldM(_ => NotFound(), Ok(_))
[warn]                                  ^
[warn] one warning found
[info] Done compiling.
```

Comment: Can you share the warning as well?

Comment: What is `Persistence.>.all()`?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin that is ZIO code - but should not have to do anything with the problem. here is the whole project: https://github.com/pme123/zio-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with **Scala 2.13**, as @jenshalm told me on Gitter. See [scala/bug#11457](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11457)

And a fix as mentioned by @rossabaker. See [http4s/issues/2933](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/issues/2933)